# OpenGL ES Async texture loading

Tags: ios, opengl-es, asynchronous

Simple question, is it possible to load texture asynchronously with iOS and OpenGL ES ?

Here is my loading method, called on a separate thread:

```
//Image size
GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);

//Create context
void *imageData = malloc(height * width * 4);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

//Prepare image
CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image.CGImage);

//Dispatch OpenGL stuff on main thread
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Bind texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, name);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
});

//Release
CGContextRelease(context);
free(imageData);
```

If I don't dispatch OpenGL calls on the main thread, my textures wont be displayed...

Same question for the glDeleteTextures call...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the same context on your background thread that you're using on the main one. For this use [setCurrentContext:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/EAGLContext/setCurrentContext%3a).
So on main thread create new thread (as an example the simplest way) and pass main context

```
[self performSelectorInBackground: @selector(loadTextureWithContext:) withObject: [EAGLContext currentContext]];
```

And the creation code:

```
-(void) loadTextureWithContext:(EAGLContext*) main_context {
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: main_context];

    //Image size
    GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);

    //Create context
    void *imageData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //Prepare image
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image.CGImage);

    //Bind texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, name);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //Release
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(imageData);

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: nil];
}
```

As an option you can also create the new context and share the same [EAGLSharegroup](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLSharegroup_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLSharegroup.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EAGLSharegroup) with the main one.

Comment: I wonder if that glBindTexture() call used to create the texture won't disrupt any drawing you may be performing in the main thread? I guess share group (= separate gl contexts) is the way to go?

Comment: @ranReloaded It could disrupt drawing if you're destroying a texture that is currently used for rendering.

Comment: No, what I meant is this: The moment you call glBindTexture() in the background thread (the one loading the texture) during the texture-creation process, whatever (previously created, fully loaded) texture you were currently using for drawing (in the main thread) gets unbound (you can only bind one texture at a time to any given context, right?)

Comment: In other words: if you want to keep doing texture-mapped rendering in the main thread while you load a texture asynchronously in a background thread, you must use two different openGL contexts linked by a share group; a single context won't cut it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ranReloaded Taken from here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html

Comment: @ranReloaded Although the context holds the OpenGL ES state, it does not directly manage OpenGL ES objects. Instead, OpenGL ES objects are created and maintained by an EAGLSharegroup object. Every context contains an EAGLSharegroup object that it delegates object creation to.

Comment: @ranReloaded and from the share group's docs: It is your application’s responsibility to manage state changes to shared objects when those objects are accessed from multiple contexts in the sharegroup. The results of changing the state of a shared object while it is being used for rendering in another context are undefined. To obtain deterministic results, your application must take explicit steps to ensure that the shared object is not currently being used for rendering while your application modifies it.

Comment: @ranReloaded so the best way to be sure that you're not using invalid texture is to use thread locks (in ObjC it is done via @synchronized)

Comment: So you are saying that the call to glBindTexture() in the background thread (to configure the texture being created) does NOT affect which texture is bound for drawing on the main thread? So we have ONE openGL context with two different textures bound at (say) GL_TEXTURE_2D, one on each thread?